# fabricjs: v2.2.1 Where are SVG paths stored on fabric object if only a single path exists on SVG

Tags: svg, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I am upgrading fabricjs in my app from version 1.7.22 to 2.2.1.

I am mainly working with SVG objects that I am creating in Illustrator. Then in the app I am manipulating paths within the SVG objects.

In v1.7.22, the svg paths would be under a 'paths' property for each object...

[image]

Now with 2.2.1, I see that 'paths' is gone, and there is an '_objects' property.

[image]

This is all good.

My problem is that the '_objects' property exists only if there is more than 1 path on the SVG object, otherwise, I can't see where the SVG path is stored.

So if it's like this...

[image]

...then '_objects' property exists. 
But if it's like this...

[image]

..then no '_objects' property.

So if there is an SVG object made with only a single path, where is the path stored in the fabric object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is mentioned in doc [groupSVGElements](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.util.html#.groupSVGElements), it returns a fabric.Object (if svg contains one path)/ fabric.Group(if svg contains more than one path).

And stated in [change log](http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes) `fabric.PathGroup` has been removed.

If it contains more than one path, creates a `fabric.Group` object containing all the `Path objects`, else returns only the path object.

To get the path use `object.path`.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"  viewBox="0 0 375 200" enable-background="new 0 0 400.5 477" xml:space="preserve"> <path d="M 100, 100m -75, 0a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0"/><path d="M250 0 L175 200 L325 200 Z" /> </svg>';

fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function(objects, options) {
  var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  console.log(shape.type)
  if(shape.type == 'group'){
   shape.forEachObject(function(obj){
    console.log(obj.path)
   })
  }
  else if(shape.type == 'path'){
    console.log(shape.path)
  }
  
  canvas.add(shape);
  document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = "Object is " + shape.type ;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<label id="label"></label>
<canvas id="c" height=300 width=400 style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. If I `canvas.getActiveObject()` on the selected object that only has one path, I do not see 'path' as one of the properties.

Comment: If I console.log(canvas.getActiveObject().type), I get "circle", not group or path.

Comment: @Serks can you make a fiddle stating your issue??

Comment: @Serks it's because it returns respective fabric object if only one element present in svg, if more it returns fabric.Group object.

Comment: I understand. Is there anyway I can duplicate the single path and return a fabric.Group object with the 2 identical paths?

Comment: @Serks Check if the `object.type == 'group' ` for group or else single object. No need to create group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167988/discussion-between-serks-and-durga).